# Which data access methodology should I use for this c# console app + Access 2007 scenario? I want Linq!

Tags: c#, database, linq, ms-access-2007

Here's our situation.

We're receiving a dump of relational data in Access 2007 format. There are quite a few tables involved. We're writing a console app in c# to run various queries against this data. We only need read-only access - we're not updating the Access database.

I haven't used Access in a project since pre-Linq days, and I'm hoping we don't have to go back to coding strings of sql against an ADO.Net connection just because the database is Access. I gather Linq 2 Sql is out of the question, but might Entity Framework be usable?

How would you approach this problem?

EDIT: The console app will be dropped by a business analyst into a folder containing the Access database, and when run will generate a text file created by querying the data. So unfortunately it's not an option to transfer the data to Sql beforehand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must keep the data into Access, you can pull it into a Dataset via ADO.NET, and then use the LINQ extension methods that work against a Dataset to work against the data.

It's not nearly as nice as working with SQL Server, but it does work.

Answer (score 1):

I would fully import the data into Sql Server, after which I would gleefully destroy all copies of the original Access file.  Then you could get as Linq-y as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Linq2Sql no, LinqXml yes! How hard would it be to dump the access file to xml?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but have you considered a SQL Server linked server to the Access file? You could then use SQL Server to do the manipulation. I don't know what the limitations/pitfalls of that are, but it's a solution often suggested when there's no good direct way to manipulate the Jet/ACE database.